# Binding WPF data grid to Sharepoint listitemcollection

Tags: list, data

I'm trying to display a sharepoint 2010 list using WPF and the Sharepoint Client object model.
This is the grid

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,37,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontFamily="Arial" Opacity="100" />
</Grid>
```

I'm able to get the list in a ListItemCollection object.The binding to WPF datagrid was done with

```
ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = listitems;
```

I'm pretty sure the listitems object is populated because I tried printing it in a separate console application and it worked.But when trying to bind the same to a datagrid, the grid just shows up empty.Tried dataGrid1.HasItems and it returns true.
What am I missing here?Why isn't any data showing up?

Comment: have you a solution? i have the same problem =(